# deactivate routing and speaking urls in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

is it possible to deactivate the speaking urls in TYPO3 9 temporarily in order to test the urls and parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Not by an option, it is possible to XCLASS the PageRouter class and generate a URL with `index.php?id=...` instead of fetching the information from the slug. However, it was never considered to allow such a mode "natively" to only have one URL per page to be generated, which helps for generating canonical URLs.

Comment: well, i removed the site definitiion temporarily ...